# Radio Checked Element Select Sass

Tags: html, css

I have a radio button that, when I check it, should affect another element.
I couldn't do it. I've tried to affect a couple of elements. Nothing worked.

My HTML markup:

```
<label for="1">
        <div class="card card-1">
            <input class="card__input-1"type="radio" name="card" id="1">    
            <h4 class="card__header">10 GB / <span class="card__header--price">0$</span></h4>
            <ul class="card__list">
                <li class="card__list-item">10GB Space</li>
                <li class="card__list-item">Sync Devices</li>
                <li class="card__list-item">Free Forever</li>
                <li class="card__list-item">No Credit Card Required</li>
            </ul>

        </div>
         </label>
```

SASS:

```
.card__input-1:checked .card-1{
background-color: orangered;
}
```

No error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `+` or `~` CSS selectors to affect elements following the input in the document flow, but which share the same parent, like so:

```css
.card__input-1:checked ~ .card-1 {
  background-color: orangered;
}
```

```html
<label for="1">
  <input class="card__input-1"type="radio" name="card" id="1"> 
 
  <div class="card card-1">
    <h4 class="card__header">10 GB / <span class="card__header--price">0$</span></h4>
    
    <ul class="card__list">
      <li class="card__list-item">10GB Space</li>
      <li class="card__list-item">Sync Devices</li>
      <li class="card__list-item">Free Forever</li>
      <li class="card__list-item">No Credit Card Required</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</label>
```

The `+` selector allows you to select an element that appears immediately after within the document flow, and the `~` selector allows you to select any element that follows (so is sort of like a "super-plus" selector).

But to affect parent elements you will need to use JavaScript